# reinstalling Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, mbr

I completely wiped Windows 7 off my machine to single boot ubuntu. I want to go back to dual boot. I have gparted, formatted, and tried to run the installation from bios/uefi chosen both usb and cd/dvd media installation methods. Nothing works it always goes straight to grub. For the other Linux lovers I only want Windows to stream to my Xbox 360. Tried vm method but couldn't get my media into the vm. My machine is a Toshiba satellite L655D

Comment: I've tried all the advice from that thread nothing worked. Now im trying to write the image to that partition and boot it. I got rescatux on hand to fix it if I break something and three other machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad to hear you have other machines, because if you continue on this project I suspect you may need them.  If you would like a slightly outside the box solution, I believe I can help you.  It may be somewhat time consuming and a bit more work but it should result in the arrangement you are seeking.

I suggest you remove the hard drive from the computer you wish to turn into a dual boot.  Install a new drive, preferably SSD, larger, or both, and install windows 7 on this new drive.  After windows is settled in, use [gparted](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gparted/) to shrink the windows 7 partition to leave enough room for your desired Ubuntu partition.  It may be necessary to use an external USB to SATA adapter (they only cost about 12) to connect this second drive externally, where you can also resize its partition to shrink it to help it fit before cloning it to the empty area of the new drive.

Finally to provide grub for both partitions with the least personal grief I suggest you use this particular [boot repair solution](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/).

Comment: Thanks, now just need to boot and nuke the old drive format it to work in my Xbox

Comment: and here I was worrying that perhaps I was careless in failing to explain how dangerous it can be to try to install windows onto a drive which has Ubuntu partitions already on it.  Perhaps you've read of that problem?

Comment: Im tired of ubuntu I wanna try all the other distros till I find a better fit. Maybe im just tired of typing my sudo password ever 15 seconds. But yeah lesson learned about ditching Windows.

Comment: Thank you @HeathJamesCadriel.  I believe you are onto something about the password thing.  I've heard that one before too, but I don't recall reading it on this site.  Maybe I missed it.  Would it be asking too much to ask you to please sum up your frustrations... rather like you did, but instead of dissing Ubuntu, instead begging for a solution, such as a sudo shortcut or programmable key combination.  If there was ever a place to find or create a solution, this would appear to be the one... well if not this, maybe launchpad.

Comment: Shit where to start. Restricted ubuntu packages, sudo passwords, ubuntu not letting me sudo rm -rf to format this hdd. Other annoyances. I'm thinking about sparky Linux because of preconfigured Windows vm's or Linux mint because Rebecca is slick.

Comment: If you want help and cooperation, it helps to keep it simple.  Here's a brainstorm of my own.  How about two passwords, one for actually logging into your account and a lesser one, like a "valet key" for making lesser changes?